# Is there a way to convert an image to an URLencoded with ImageJ Jython script?

Tags: python, base64, urlencode, imagej

I would love to encode the currently opened image by the user (in ImageJ, Fiji) to a string or directly to an URL so the image can be interpreted by a brother

regarding a project of externalized training model that will apply filters (removing noises) on the image, "repack" it into URL encode (passing by a toString if needed) and resend it to the user (plugin fiji will decode URL to display new treated image)

i've tried to use the imageplus format, i can have an array of byte of my image with the BufferedImage but it seems I can't go further for making it an URL encoded

I'm struggling finding a way (working on imageJ) to have it directly in URL or even passing by base64 since it doesn't work on imageJ, is it normal ?

```
from ij import IJ
from java.awt.image import BufferedImage
from java.io import ByteArrayOutputStream
from java.io import File 
from javax.imageio import ImageIO
from java.util import Base64 
from java.lang import StringBuffer
import base64
import json


#imagePlus will get the currently opened image
imp = IJ.getImage()

#buffered image
buffered = imp.getBufferedImage()
print(imp.getCurrentSlice())

#Byte Array conversion
baos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
ImageIO.write( buffered, "PNG", baos )
print(baos.size())
baos.flush()
imageInByte = baos.toByteArray()
baos.close()

print(len(imageInByte))

#ImageJ doesn't like this at all

#dataStr = json.dumps(imageInByte)
#base64EncodedStr = base64.b64encode(dataStr)
#print(base64EncodedStr)

print(type(imageInByte[0]))
```

this is my Array of Bytes version of the image which I can't exploit anymore

I'm sure there is a way to have this image in URL encode but everything i've tried such as "directly to URL" or base64 aren't working (interpreted by imageJ) or Something. I also cannot convert my array of byte to a string because I'd need numpy libraries to do so and ImageJ doesn't support it 
and I can't do this bytes format as a list for a toString.

i'll take any idea coming here since i never got answer in JavaScript and had to translate it in Python because I though solutions would be more "known"

I've tried second method

```
import json
import base64
from ij import IJ


imageFile = IJ.getImage()

myStringImage = base64.b64encode(imageFile)
print(myStringImage)
print(type(myStringImage))
```

I need to do a thing as simple as this, but this give me a type error for :

```
TypeError: b2a_base64(): 1st arg can't be coerced to org.python.core.BufferProtocol
```

If there is a way to do it, it's not working for some "type" or "defined" question... 
i'm sure regarding all the thing you can do with ImageJ? what i'm asking is not that impossible.. it cannot be

Comment: It seems the biggest problem comes from the ImagePlus format that limit a lots the treatment such as "string" "base64" and other

I used the most commont method of charging a local image (that's too bad i'll need to do this for every image that every user will ever treat, not for a single one every time) 

Now I at least have a base64 encoded image , but can I really make this base64 string an URL readable by brother ? I don't think so..

is this that impossible ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I needed to add this (got few hope when i test this)

```
from org.apache.commons.codec.binary import Base64;
```

Then I had to simply encode this way :

```
stringImage = Base64.encodeBase64String(baos.toByteArray())
```

And this is readable by browser

Now I have to imagine an URL image (the in-the-future need-to-be filtered image sent via URL that will be passed in the deep learning model)

**How can I do this in the reverse way ? decode a base64 image into a .PNG on ImageJ and then, display it ?**

Comment: The difficultie consists most of the time about ImageJ not letting me import the 
PIL librarie or the numpy ...

Answer (score 0):

Update ! here's the solution i've found

```
# writing the base64 into a textfile
new_file = open('imageCode.txt', 'w')
new_file.write(s)
new_file.close()

# decode base64 and create image (in the future, the filtered one, here the same) in .png
new_file_decode = open('imageDecode.png', 'wb')
new_file_decode.write(base64.b64decode(s))
new_file_decode.close()

# display image
IJ.open('imageDecode.png')
```

My new problem here is to delete the file that are supposed to be "temporary" 
everytime someone will use this.

the console say "unknow error occured" when I want to delete the Decoded image and the imageCode.txt
Saying it's "used by another thing" but as you see in the code I "close" them ...
I dont want user to have many images in the folder, so i'd like to delete them but I can't proceed

Comment: `os.remove("imageDecode.png")
os.remove("imageCode.txt")` at some point I gave up and restarting FiJi fixed my problem !